# jomsocial - restrict access to users type com_user

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7, jomsocial

I have two different login.
one is for simple users (com_user)
one is for users of social networking (including JomSocial)

I have the 2.5.7 version of joomla and the version of JomSocial 2.6.1

How can I prevent users easy access to socialnetwork?

I tried this but it does not work.

```
$userattr = JFactory::getUser();
$condition = $userattr->get('usertype');
if ($condition == 'Registered') { 
  redirect user to login page
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work.

`    $userattr = JFactory::getUser();
    $condition = $userattr->get('attribute');
      if ($condition == 'return value') { 
    redirect user to login page
 } `

Comment: What result is when you put `var_dump($condition); exit;` into code as a results?

Comment: result is: string(1) "2"

Answer (score 1):

Jomsocial access depends on the access level of the menu items in the jomsocial menu.

So just create a new group for jomsocial users (i.e. jomsocialregistered) and assign the jomsocial menu items.  This will leave you the task of assigning correctly the jomsocial users to this newly created group, but I don't know how you plan to achieve this.